# Following Bubble sort not working in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort, cs50

I am writing a sort function to implement a bubble sort in C but it is not sorting the given array. Here is the following code. I am using a void function so I cannot return the array and have to make changes in the existing array. The code compiles well and runs but it does not sort the array.

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int sp = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (values[i] > values[i + 1])
            {
                int first_val = values[i];
                int second_val = values[i + 1];

                values[i] = second_val;
                values[i + 1] = first_val;
                sp = 1;
            }
        }
        if (sp == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `i` is at `n-1`, you're comparing `values[n-1]` with `values[n]` and there is no `values[n]` in the array (the indexes run `0..n-1`).  This is undefined behaviour and leads to wrong results.  There may be other problems, but that's an important starting issue that will need to be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bubble Sort, n-1 comparisons will be done in 1st pass, n-2 in 2nd pass, n-3 in 3rd pass and so on. So the total number of comparisons will be

```
(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+.....+3+2+1
Sum = n(n-1)/2
i.e O(n2)
```

So two things you need to change in your code :-

1. condition in inner loop will be for(j=0;j< n-i-1;j++).
2. No need to take two variable to swap data. Space complexity for Bubble Sort is O(1), because only single additional memory space is required for temp variaable.

Answer (score 3):

You access  `values[i + 1]` by saying `values[i] > values[i + 1]`. So natural limit of `i` should be `n-1`

```
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be working now with the following code:

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int sp = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            if (values[j] > values[j + 1])
            {
                int first_val = values[j];
                int second_val = values[j + 1];

                values[j] = second_val;
                values[j + 1] = first_val;
                sp = 1;
            }
        }
        if (sp == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

}